# Filtering Json Data by Current Date

Tags: jquery, json

Pretty much just trying to display the next 3 current games by date. I would like to see the dates of the next 3 games and and have it account for a game if it is happening the day of (current date at the moment user is viewing).

```
$.getJSON('http://data.nba.com/data/v2015/json/mobile_teams/nba/2020/teams/trail_blazers_schedule_02.json', function(data) {

    var currentDate = new Date();

    $(data.gscd.g).each(function (index, value) {

        for(var i = 0; i < 1; i++){

            document.write('<h4>'+value.gdte+'</h4>');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: i dont understant your problem, following your json sample, could you show what you want to display?

Comment: @Frenchy Just want to display the current next 3 game dates. So <h4>01-30-2021</h4> <h4>02-04-2021</h4> <h4>02-07-2021</h4>

What I currently get with that function is ALL dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by making 3 operations: 1) filter games to remove past events, 2) sort games by date, 3) select 3 games. Something like this:

```
    $.getJSON('http://data.nba.com/data/v2015/json/mobile_teams/nba/2020/teams/trail_blazers_schedule_02.json', function(data) {
        var currentDate = new Date();

        // 1. filter
        var filtered = data.gscd.g.filter((entry) => Date.parse(entry.gdte) > currentDate);
        // 2. sort
        filtered.sort((a, b) => Date.parse(b.gdte) - Date.parse(b.gdte));
        // 3. get 3 games
        var result = filtered.slice(0,3)
    
        $(result).each(function (index, value) {
                document.write('<h4>'+value.gdte+'</h4>');
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly! Would you happen to know how to go about it reading the date in a different format? Like Sat, Jan 30. As well as converting military time for the 'etm' portion? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I use `moment` library or `date-fns` to parse dates in different formats: `moment('Sat, Jan 30', 'ddd, MMM DD').toDate()`. Parsing dates with vanilla JavaScript is much harder.

Comment: When using moment.js would .toDate() be replacing Date.parse? Can you show how it would work with the example above?

Comment: `Date.parse` returns the time in milliseconds. In moment you can get the same value using: `moment('Sat, Jan 30', 'ddd, MMM DD').valueOf()`

Comment: It did not seem to work for me. Does ```.valueOf() ``` replace ```.parse()```? I changed ```var currentDate = new Date();``` to ```var currentDate = moment('Sat, Jan 30', 'ddd, MMM DD').valueOf()``` and that did not work either.

Comment: You don't need to do any changes to current date, it is correct as it is. Can you somehow show me all your code?

Comment: It is the one you provided above. It is just outputting in the wrong date format. It is outputting 'Year-Month-Date or 2021-02-04' when I need it to display as 'ddd, MMM DD'. That is all I need to fix it the format :)

Comment: If you need to output that value in that value, then probably this way: `document.write('<h4>'+moment(value.gdte, 'YYYY-MM-DD').format('ddd, MMM DD')+'</h4>');`

Comment: It worked, thanks! I appreciate your time on this.